# Google Maps Clustering markers for website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to show a lot of markers on a map for my website.

The question i have is whether google maps api for javascript for website still provides clustering ? I have tried marker cluster and i think it does not work now.
If yes could anybody let me know how to achieve it. 
If no, does anybody has an alternative?

Comment: what do you mean by "Weather" google map?

Comment: i meant "whether" :)

Comment: if its not working for you, send me you code and i'll be happy to have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

Yes! it is still available see examples: [Google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markerclusterer)